# htaccess access to file by ip range

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to allow access to file only to users with ip which are in a range of ip addresses?

For example file admin.php. and range from 0.0.0.0 to 1.2.3.4.

I need configure access to only ONE file not to directory.

Comment: Allow from FROM_IP TO_IP

Comment: @Manish Trivedi Just tried it: 127.0.0.1 is denied by 127.0.0.0 127.0.0.2 . Therefore, it's not that simple - unless I made a mistake in my test. Did I?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just add a [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#filesmatch) or [Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files) directive to limit it to a specific script.

The following would block acces to all scripts ending in "admin.php" :

```
<FilesMatch "admin\.php$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/24
</FilesMatch>
```

The following would ONLY block admin.php :

```
<Files "admin.php">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/24
</Files>
```

For more information refer to the apache docs on [Configuration Sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html#filesystem).

Answer (score 36):

check the man page of the [Allow Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow)

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

**A partial IP address**

*Example:*

```
Allow from 10.1
Allow from 10 172.20 192.168.2
```

The first 1 to 3 bytes of an IP address, for subnet restriction.

**A network/netmask pair**

*Example:*

```
Allow from 10.1.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

A network a.b.c.d, and a netmask w.x.y.z. For more fine-grained subnet restriction.

**A network/nnn CIDR specification**

*Example:*

```
Allow from 10.1.0.0/16
```

Similar to the previous case, except the netmask consists of nnn high-order 1 bits.

Comment: But how to use it for example for admin.php file?

Comment: Am I on the right lines here to adding 2 ip ranges to my allow from code in htaccess? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833456/how-do-i-allow-these-two-ip-ranges-in-my-htaccess-file

Comment: "the netmask consists of nnn high-order 1 bits." - what does that mean? Is it about the "/16"? I see this notation often, but have yet to find an explanation for it.

Comment: Got it, came across by accident: the secret word is "CIDR-Format"

Answer (score 11):

You cannot match an IP range with [allow](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow), but you can emulate it with a CIDR notation:

```
Order allow,deny

# 0.0.0.0 - 0.255.255.255.255
Allow from 0.0.0.0/8

# 1.0.0.0 - 1.1.255.255
Allow from 1.0.0.0/15

# 1.2.0.0 - 1.2.1.255
Allow from 1.2.0.0/23

# 1.2.2.0 - 1.2.2.255
Allow from 1.2.2.0/24

# 1.2.3.0 - 1.2.3.3
Allow from 1.2.3.0/30

# 1.2.3.4
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do this for a single IP:

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.2.3.4
</Limit>
```

If you want to do it for a range like 10.x.x.x, then do this:

```
<Limit GET POST> 
order allow,deny 
allow from 10
deny from all
</LIMIT>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WordPress, then the Best and Simplest method is to install the plugin - **LionScripts : WordPress IP Blocker** from their website http://www.lionscripts.com/ip-address-blocker

Their Professional version has much more features like country blocking and IP range blocking, bulk csv uploading etc.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it will restrict uploaded files though.

Answer (score 1):

if you to provide a wildcard 0.0.255.255

```
Order allow,deny
# 1.2.0.0 - 1.2.255.255
Allow from 1.2.0.0/16
```

This will give a range from 1.2.0.1 - 1.2.255.254

you can also [check here](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=1.2.0.0&mask1=16&mask2=)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to redirect all but cetain Ip's to a maintenance page - our IPs all on same network - The following worked based on shamitomar's answer above :

```
# TEMP MAINTENANCE PAGE
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
# One address that is on a diffrent network
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
#allow all addresses from our network
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xxx

#Stuff to allow so that we can show our maintenance page while we work
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(styles|images).+$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|js|css|ttf|woff) [NC] 
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 311.311.311 322.322.322.322
```

See [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593922/ip-restriction-with-htaccess)

Comment: This matches just the specified IP addresses, not a range.