# How do I allow these two IP ranges in my htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I currently allow the following 2 specific IP addresses access to my dev server without a password:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/server/htdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from 11.125.19.12
Allow from 11.59.193.12
satisfy any
```

WorldPay have just sent me these 2 ranges of IP addresses - how do I add those to my allow list? Does it work differently for ranges?

**Possible solution 1:**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/server/htdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from 11.125.19.12
Allow from 11.59.193.12
Allow from 195.35.90
Allow from 195.35.91
satisfy any
```

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042399/htaccess-access-to-file-by-ip-range

Comment: Is it the partial address method? Please check my edited post for Possible Solution 1. How does that look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution you posted will allow the ranges 195.35.90.1 - 195.35.90.255 and 195.35.91.1 - 195.35.91.255 in addition to the 11.x.x.x IPs you allowed.

You can check out [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) for more details on the syntax of the `Allow` directive.

Comment: In that case I think that'll work! I shall get testing. Thank you!